# Issue about correct and fast seeking in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a question about correct and fast seeking in php array.

I have input array:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'Videos' => 
        array (size=2)
          240 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          120 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      'Texts' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'Price' => float 0
      'QaAudio' => int 1
      'QaVideo' => int 3
      'Level' => string 'normal' (length=6)
      'PreviewPic' => 
        array (size=7)
          40 => 
            array (size=12)
              ...
          60 => 
            array (size=12)
              ...
          140 => 
            array (size=12)
              ...
          160 => 
            array (size=12)
              ...
          320 => 
            array (size=12)
              ...
          640 => 
            array (size=12)
              ...
          1024 => 
            array (size=12)
              ...
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      'Videos' => 
       array (size=3)
          480 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          360 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          120 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      'Texts' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'Price' => float 0
      'QaAudio' => int 1
      'QaVideo' => int 3
      'Level' => string 'sexy' (length=4)
      'PreviewPic' => 
        array (size=7)
          40 => 
            array (size=12)
              ...
          60 => 
            array (size=12)
              ...
          140 => 
            array (size=12)
              ...
          160 => 
            array (size=12)
              ...
          320 => 
            array (size=12)
              ...
          640 => 
            array (size=12)
              ...
          1024 => 
            array (size=12)
              ...
```

I need to find in it the video, that has max value in Videos key.(it has 360,240,120 values as you can see in example) and has Level Key that equal to 'normal' or 'sexy' value.

I wrote some method to do it:

```
public function getPresentationVideo($id)
    {
        $result = [];
        $notHardVideos = [];
        $profileVideos = $this->getProfilesVideos($id,0,50);
        if ($profileVideos && count($profileVideos) > 0) {
            foreach ($profileVideos as $video) {
                if (in_array($video['Level'],['normal','sexy'])) {
                    $video['maxVideoQuality'] = max(array_keys($video['Videos']));
                    $notHardVideos[] = $video;
                }
            }
            $keyForMaxQuality = 0;
            if (count($notHardVideos) > 1) {
                $maxQuality = 0;
                foreach($notHardVideos as $key => $video) {
                    if($video['maxVideoQuality'] > $maxQuality)
                    {
                        $maxQuality = $video['maxVideoQuality'];
                        $keyForMaxQuality = $key;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (count($notHardVideos) > 0) {
                $result = $notHardVideos[$keyForMaxQuality];
                unset($result['maxVideoQuality']);
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

It do it well.

But i wonder is there any more effective way to do it.
Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array_reduce($videos, function ($result, array $video) {
    if (!in_array($video['Level'], ['normal', 'sexy'])) {
        return $result;
    }
    if (!$result) {
        return $video;
    }
    if (max(array_keys($video['Videos'])) > max(array_keys($result['Videos']))) {
        return $video;
    }
    return $result;
});
```

This will return the sub array which has a 'normal' or 'sexy' level (BTW, FTW?!) and which has the highest key in its 'Videos' sub array. It doesn't include any other considerations, as you seem to have in your code, because you did not specify exactly what those considerations are. However, you should get the idea and can add more checks if you need.

See http://php.net/array_reduce for help with this function. In short, this takes each element in the array in turn and compares it to the previous best candidate. I.e., `$result` will be nothing at first, but when you have found a 'normal' or 'sexy' video it will become that video, and on subsequent calls the video with the higher keys will win.